# Scaling of icons does not work for gtkmm applications

Tags: environment-variables, x-resources, high-dpi

I have a 4K display, and the correct scaling would be 3x. I have put

```
Xft.dpi: 300
```

in `.Xresources` and

```
GDK_SCALE=3
GDK_DPI_SCALE=-1
```

in `/etc/environment`.

This can scale most applications, but the C++ applications that use `gtkmm` do not scale. Some apps are Nitrogen and GParted. Using this method, the text scales but not the icons. How do I scale the icons for `gtkmm` applications?